# Error when connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

When I'm trying to connect to my database I'm getting this error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

And yes it's the right connection for my local database.

Comment: Is SQLExpress running? Look in Services and make sure it is running. Also, this is not a even a decent question for this site. You might try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe that you can get an answer in google.  Its a common error

Comment: Apesa what do you mean?

Comment: if you type out the error rather than pasting a screen shot, it would be more useful for indexing, and in fact u might find the answer.

Comment: Please paste the error text inside your question, otherwise other developers will not find the solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Start Menu > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager` and have a look at the screen you're seeing:

[image]

Do you see a service on the right-hand side that says `SQL Server (.....) running`? If so - the text in the brackets is your *instance name* - use that instance name to connect to your database server:

```
.\instance-name
(local)\instance-name
```

If the instance name says `MSSQLSERVER`, then you have an unnamed *default instance* - do *not* specify any instance name for connecting:

```
.
(local)
```

If you do not see any "SQL Server" service that is running --> you don't have any database engine installed and up and running

Comment: That fixed it thanks alot! It was the SQL server (SQLEXPRESS) it was at state = Stopped Thanks!